Avalonia Background Jobs
How to connect background tasks to Avalonia. Conditionally, I need messages to be uploaded to a file every 5 minutes in my desktop application for windows and linux. I didn't find a question on this topic on GitHub and it talked about the AsyncAwaitBestPractices. However, it only implements the SaveFireAndForget method. Which is not suitable in this case.
I tried to do it with Quartz.NET, but it doesn't works.
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static void AddCommonServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IFileService, FileService>();
        services.AddTransient<MainWindowViewModel>();

        services.AddQuartz(option =>
        {
            var jobKey = JobKey.Create(nameof(LoggingBackgroundJob));
            option
                .AddJob<LoggingBackgroundJob>(jobKey)
                .AddTrigger(trigger =>
                    trigger
                        .ForJob(jobKey)
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule =>
                            schedule.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever()
                        )
                );
        });

        services.AddQuartzHostedService(option =>
        {
            option.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });
    }
}


namespace AvaloniaApplication1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }

        public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
        {
            if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
            {
                // Line below is needed to remove Avalonia data validation.
                // Without this line you will get duplicate validations from both Avalonia and CT
                BindingPlugins.DataValidators.RemoveAt(0);

                var collection = new ServiceCollection();
                collection.AddCommonServices();

                var services = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

                var vm = services.GetRequiredService<MainWindowViewModel>();
                desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
                {
                    DataContext = vm
                };
            }

            base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
        }
    }
}

